# Error Unable connect to SQL Server when add <roleManager enabled="true">

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

When I add

```
<roleManager enabled="true"></roleManager>
```

to my `web.config`, I get an error

> Unable to connect to SQL Server database

occurs on this line of code:

```
System.Web.Security.Roles.AddUserToRole(m.UserName, "admin");
```

Comment: when edit in web.config <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="CustomizedRoleProvider">
   <providers>
      <add name="CustomizedRoleProvider"  type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="conStr" />
   </providers>
</roleManager> error {"Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'."}

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I added this to the web.config and it solved my problem:

```
 <system.web>
     <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="CustomizedRoleProvider">
          <providers>
            <add name="CustomizedRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
          </providers>
        </roleManager>
 </system.web>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same error when I had enabled  believing I was enabling ASP.NET Identity 2. They are not the same! The  enabled an old version of identity management which uses a different table structure to ASP.NET Identity 2 (which doesn't need "enabling" by the way - it's just there).

check the connection String.

If you are intentionally using the old role-manager and still getting the error you might be looking at the default localdb instead of your database, in which case you can modify  to point at any connection string you want:

```html
<roleManager
      enabled="true"
      cacheRolesInCookie="true"
      defaultProvider="OurSqlRoleProvider"
     >
      <providers>
          <add
             connectionStringName="DefaultConnection"
             applicationName="/"
             name="OurSqlRoleProvider"
             type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" />
      </providers>

  </roleManager>
```

If you are are after using ASP.NET Identity 2, here's an article on it:
http://johnatten.com/2014/04/20/asp-net-mvc-and-identity-2-0-understanding-the-basics/